# warning in importing a CSV to R; "-" not meaningful for factors

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a set of dates from CSV to R.

Code:

```
dates <-- read.csv(file="dates.csv",header=FALSE)
```

Result:

> Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

The result is a bunch of NAs.

CSV file when opened in Notepad:

```
31/07/2014
30/07/2014
29/07/2014
28/07/2014
25/07/2014
24/07/2014
23/07/2014
22/07/2014
21/07/2014
18/07/2014
17/07/2014
16/07/2014
15/07/2014
14/07/2014
11/07/2014
10/07/2014
9/07/2014
8/07/2014
7/07/2014
4/07/2014
3/07/2014
2/07/2014
1/07/2014
30/06/2014
27/06/2014
26/06/2014
25/06/2014
24/06/2014
23/06/2014
20/06/2014
19/06/2014
18/06/2014
17/06/2014
16/06/2014
13/06/2014
12/06/2014
11/06/2014
10/06/2014
9/06/2014
6/06/2014
```

Comment: Since you are a new user, also try reading the tour, in order to know the many things you can do in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `<-` operator, which is the standard `assignment operator` in R.

```
dates <- read.csv(file = "dates.csv", header = FALSE)
```

instead of the one you are typing above.

You could also read [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html) for the different assignment operators used in R.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you happen to know why <-- worked for other commands like read.csv?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out. The second - made the numbers negative.

Comment: Since you are new to SO, saying "thank you" is discouraged. In order to demonstrate that an answer has helped you, you could either "accept" the answer (press the tick on the left of the question) or/and upvote it. Have a nice day.